# How to wrap raw h264 stream into mp4 file?

Tags: python, mp4, h.264

I'm getting a raw h264 stream from a hardware encoder and want to save it as an mp4. All I found so far about that were libs to convert or reencode a stream, but that's not what I want. I just want to generate a propper mp4 container for my stream data.

How to do that in python?

Comment: `mp4box` maybe?